Why the type of the iterator to `std::views::transform` does not seem to be a deterministic type?
I want to get the type of the iterator to the const-casted contents of the vector. I thought I can use decltype for it.
Apparently it is not that simple.
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

const int& cast_const(int& i)  {
   return i;
}

struct PoC {
   std::vector<int> _m;
   decltype(_m | std::views::transform(cast_const)) _const = _m | std::views::transform(cast_const);
   using const_iterator = decltype(_const.begin());
   [[nodiscard]] auto cbegin() const { return _const.begin(); }
   using iterator = decltype(_m.begin());
   [[nodiscard]] auto begin() { return _m.begin(); }
};

void test() {
   PoC p;
   PoC::const_iterator cit = p.cbegin(); // ERROR: error: conversion from ‘_Iterator<true>’ to non-scalar type ‘_Iterator<false>’ requested
   PoC::iterator it = p.begin(); // Works, because no ranges.
}

I believe it boils down to the fact, that PoC::const_iterator is of type`
std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> >, int& (*)(int&)>::_Iterator<false>

while the return value of p.cbegin() is of type
std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> >, int& (*)(int&)>::_Iterator<true>

The argument type of the _Iterator is named _Const in the source code for ranges.
Can you explain to me the reason, the ranges are so designed? Is the problem fixable, or should I build the const_iterator from scratch, and not use the ranges?

edit:
I've posted a follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78874243/1261153: what if we turn simplify into get_const that returns a smart pointer to a const X. Surprisingly this complicates the problem.


Can you explain to me the reason why the ranges are so designed?
Is the problem fixable, or should I build the const_iterator from scratch, and not use the ranges?

I do not know the design part of range iterators. However, the problem can be fixed.
After digging a bit, I found out that ranges have a set of helpers like std::ranges::const_iterator_t (since c++23), which essentially helps to retrieve the corresponding iterator. That means, the issue can be fixed by:
struct PoC 
{
   std::vector<int> _m;
   const decltype(_m | std::views::transform(cast_const)) _const = ...
// ^^^^ --> added const

   using const_iterator = std::ranges::const_iterator_t<decltype(_const)>;
   //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ used to retrieve the iterator!
  
  // ...Rest of the code
};

See live demo

In c++20, however, you have only std::ranges::iterator_t option, by which you might do:

struct PoC 
{
   std::vector<int> _m;
   decltype(_m | std::views::transform(cast_const)) _const = ....

   using const_iterator = std::ranges::iterator_t<const decltype(_const)>;
   //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   // ...Rest of the code
};

See live demo

As a side note, you could have make use of std::as_const(since C++17) in a lambda function, instead of the custom cast_const() function.

There is no need to use views::transform to do this, the standard already has a specific view for such utility, namely views::as_const in C++23:
std::vector<int> m;
auto cm = m | std::views::as_const; // read-only view for the original vector

Replacing the views::transform(cast_const) part of your original example with views::as_const also works.
Demo

Thank you for the answer. Too bad I can't compile it gcc 12.3...

FYI, after giving it a thought to the simplicity of your solution, I seriously consider advocating for upgrading our toolchain.

The only thing you need to fix the issue is to replace
using const_iterator = decltype(_const.begin());

with
using const_iterator = decltype(std::as_const(_const).begin()); // needs #include <utility>

You can't really blame STL or ranges for forbidding casting const iterators into non-const iterators. That's a sanity check.

I failed to find this part of the C++ std lib. Thank you very much! I've learned something useful.
