Why does std::stable_sort not compile when std::sort does?
This is a follow-up question to Why std::stable_sort does not compile when std::sort does?
The problem is the same, except the simplify is now called get_const and returns a smart pointer to the const X.
The bigger picture is that I want to have a container of X, that can be cast (without copying) to a container of const X. Currently I implemented it as a base class ContainerOfConstX that holds std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>> _m and two views: one _const = _m | std::views::transform(get_const); and the other as _mutable = _m | std::views::transform(simplify);. There is a Derived class ContainerOfX that serves functions based on _mutable.
All two containers expose the natural functions to their names, such as begin(), end(), front(), back(), push_back(std::shared_ptr<[const] X>), etc. with the expected semantics.
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct X {
   X(int x) : mx(x) {}
   int mx;
};

std::shared_ptr<const X>& get_const(std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>& i) {
   return get_underlying(i); // error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr<const X>&’ from expression of type ‘std::shared_ptr<X>’
}

int operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<X>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<X>& rhs) {
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>> m; //originally a member variable of a class that works as custom container of X.
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(4));
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(2));
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(3));
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(1));
   
   // Some code that works with vector of non-const Xs.

   decltype(m | std::views::transform(get_const)) r = m | std::views::transform(get_const);

   // Some code that works with vector of const X. In particular:

   std::sort(r.begin(), r.end()); 
   std::stable_sort(r.begin(), r.end());
}

Maybe the issue is with the std::experimental::propagate_const? I would very much prefer not to use it at all, because in the end I need to target msvc as well.
Please note, that making the argument to get_const const gets the code compile (not on clang, though), with the warning message: warning: returning reference to temporary: return get_underlying(i)
Godbolt link

Your swap function effectively does nothing, because you pass the arguments by value. Why are you even creating your own function?

And what is get_underlying?  I can't find it on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

@Someprogrammerdude https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const/get_underlying

please include the error message in the question. With gcc your code fails due to cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::shared_ptr<const X>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::shared_ptr<const X>' and some more errors out of which on first sight none is related to std::sort vs std::stable_sort

std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>> that just looks wrong by design.  Our vector of pointers to X is treated as pointers to const X when the pointer itself is const?  Ok, I guess that works.

But the get_const transform is a std::vector<const T>?  If so, you can [mcve] by actually using that type.  If not, the type would be useful to know.

This question is misleading because neither sort nor stable_sort can work because you cannot satisfy the required Random Iterator which needs to return a reference and you cannot provide a reference to something that doesn't exist, and shared_ptr<const X>& cannot refer to shared_ptr<X>&. (you can get it to work by reinterpret_cast but it would be UB, you would at least violate the strict aliasing rule).
If you really need this code to work then you need to allow the user to get non-const access to the container to get a Random iterator if he really needs it to modify the vector, and you later need to catch improper use of this in code-reviews.
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct X {
   X(int x) : mx(x) {}
   int mx;
};

std::shared_ptr<const X> get_const(std::shared_ptr<X>& i) {
   return i;
}

int operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<X>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<X>& rhs) {
   return 0;
}

template <typename T>
struct constSpan
{
    constSpan(std::vector<T>& vec): r{vec | std::views::transform(get_const)} {}
    auto begin() const { return r.begin();}
    auto end() const {return r.end();}
    auto cbegin() const {return r.cbegin();}
    auto cend() const {return r.cend();}
    const auto& operator[](size_t idx) const {return r[idx];}
    std::vector<T>& Base() {return r.base().base();}
    private:    
    decltype(std::declval<std::vector<T>&>() | std::views::transform(get_const)) r;
};

int main() {
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> m; 

   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(4));
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(2));
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(3));
   m.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(1));
   constSpan r{m};
   
   std::sort(r.Base().begin(), r.Base().end()); 
   std::stable_sort(r.Base().begin(), r.Base().end());
}

Another alternative is to make Base private and only expose sort and similar functions, ie: "interior mutability", this would be a better option if you want to ban improper access to the underlying container, note that anyone can still get non-const access to the underlying container, it just takes more code to do that, just like how you can get the underlying container of std::views::transform or cast away const.
Or you can just not provide non-const access to the underlying container, and anyone that wants to sort the vector or modify it will have to get the non-const access from somewhere else.
